# Redshifts, distance and speed of recession

Tags: general-relativity

In Robertson-Walker universe, light is emitted from a star with spatial coordinates $(r_s,\theta_s,\phi_s)$. It travels radially inwards and is received by an observer situated at the origin $(r=0)$. Show that the ratio of the observed wavelength $\lambda$ to the proper wavelength $\lambda_0)$ is given by $$\lambda /\lambda_0=R(t_2)/R(t_1),$$
where $t_1$ is the time of emision, and $t_2$ is the time of reception.

Comment: Doy you mean *spatial* coordinates? And what is $R(t)$?

Comment: This might be better placed at http://phyiscs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @draks From the context it looks like he means *spherical* coordinates.

Comment: I think that in order to be able to answer the question, we should exactly know which [coordinate representation of the metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) he is talking about.